# run program but not if already running

Tags: batch-file

I need to check if a process is running on my computer, and if it's not, start it, otherwise don't start another one.

The catch is, this needs to be directory specific

E.g. I want to run `F:\PVE Server\ShooterGame\Binaries\Win64\start.exe` if it's not already running, but ignore other `start.exe`s in other directories that may already be running.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [2-minute tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Moreover, open [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read at least _What topics can I ask about here_? 
Then you know what we expect from questioners: showing us the code ([mcve]) on where you stuck solving the task by yourself and explaining why you fail to complete the task. Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. HINT: start with `wmic process where "caption like 'start%%'" get Caption, CommandLine`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this using [WMIC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) :

```
@echo off
wmic process get executablepath | find /i "F:\PVE Server\ShooterGame\Binaries\Win64\start.exe"
set result=%ERRORLEVEL%
if "%result%"=="1" echo "not running"
if "%result%"=="0" echo "running"
```

Comment: OK but how can I run the process if its not running

Comment: replace the `echo` command with your `start` command.